# IE10 - unable to prevent cache for iframe

Tags: caching, iframe, internet-explorer-10, html5-appcache

I have modal boxes on a page are opening dynamic content in iframes.

`<a href="popup.php?id=52" rel="modal">Link 1</a>` (fixed id)

`<a href="popup.php?id=53" rel="modal">Link 1</a>` (fixed id)
...

But whatever I do, I can't prevent iframe content to be cached in IE10 (seems to other browsers are good).

- I use html5 so meta tags are helpless.
- Cache.manifest made my page messed up (or if to put just NETWORK: * - no effect).
- PHP headers `header("Cache-Control: no-cache"); header("Expires: -1");` also gives no effect for IE10.
- JS/JQuery solutions found in web I couldn't apply correctly.

Any solution except to add another dynamic GET parameter for href ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work in IE10, but a few years ago Firefox had a similar issue with caching the content of iframes, and a trick to make it reload was to use JavaScript to force a reload like this:

```
var orig_src = iframe.src;
iframe.src = "blank.html"; # A blank document you'll need to create
setTimeout(function() { iframe.src = orig_src; }, 100);
```

or the simpler technique of

```
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

... which also may or may not work in IE10.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work for me, both. Tried to put in parent page and inside of iframe. Actually current FF reloads iframes just perfect but IE10 not, it just caches it very hard and I able to renew page only by selecting Refresh in right click menu.